# AdMob crashes emulator when launching app repeatedly

Tags: android, debugging, admob, ads

I'm trying to debug an app that has ads in it, and the emulator is crashing on me. It seems silly that I have to manually set it to test mode, when I'm trying to test out my code. Is there someway to prevent this from happening, perhapse detect if its in emulator mode and have it set the adRequest to test mode? Has anyone else been able to overcome this or experienced it? I can't recreate the problem on my phone at least.

Here is the code section that I think is causing me problems, when I'm using the Android emulator:

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxx");
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.adview_layout);
layout.addView(adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Here is the log from LogCat:

```
07-05 10:45:10.627: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Starting activity: Intent { dat=content://com.simpleclock.widget/appwidgets/1 cmp=hobodroid.clock.widget/.Settings (has extras) }
07-05 10:45:10.627: WARN/ActivityManager(70): startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { dat=content://com.simpleclock.widget/appwidgets/1 cmp=hobodroid.clock.widget/.Settings (has extras) }
07-05 10:45:10.977: INFO/Ads(3527): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
07-05 10:45:11.037: INFO/Ads(3527): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://www.gstatic.com/afma/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"msid":"hobodroid.clock.widget","simulator":1,"hl":"en","preqs":1,"u_so":"p","slotname":"a14e0eda6eb26ea","js":"afma-sdk-a-v4.1.0","app_name":"8.android.hobodroid.clock.widget","isu":"B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB","u_audio":4,"u_w":320,"cap":"m,a","format":"320x50_mb","u_sd":1.5,"net":"ed","u_h":533});</script></head><body></body></html>
07-05 10:45:11.307: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Displayed activity hobodroid.clock.widget/.Settings: 662 ms (total 662 ms)
07-05 10:45:11.947: INFO/Ads(3527): Received ad url: <"url": "http://r.admob.com:80/ad_source.php?msid=hobodroid.clock.widget&hl=en&preqs=1&u_so=p&slotname=a14e0eda6eb26ea&js=afma-sdk-a-v4.1.0&app_name=8.android.hobodroid.clock.widget&isu=B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB&u_audio=4&u_w=320&cap=m%2Ca&format=320x50_mb&u_sd=1.5&net=ed&u_h=533&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=-120&ex=1&client_sdk=1&askip=1", "afmaNotifyDt": "null">
07-05 10:45:12.427: INFO/Ads(3527): onReceiveAd()
07-05 10:45:13.217: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(3527): No keyboard for id 0
07-05 10:45:13.217: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(3527): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
07-05 10:45:14.307: INFO/DEBUG(27): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
07-05 10:45:14.317: INFO/DEBUG(27): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:1.6/Donut/20842:eng/test-keys'
07-05 10:45:14.317: INFO/DEBUG(27): pid: 3527, tid: 3537  >>> hobodroid.clock.widget <<<
07-05 10:45:14.317: INFO/DEBUG(27): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000000
07-05 10:45:14.317: INFO/DEBUG(27):  r0 00000007  r1 411b9a50  r2 411b9a50  r3 00000000
07-05 10:45:14.317: INFO/DEBUG(27):  r4 411b9a50  r5 00280df0  r6 00000000  r7 44cc8cac
07-05 10:45:14.317: INFO/DEBUG(27):  r8 44cc8da0  r9 424c2e48  10 424c2e34  fp 00000001
07-05 10:45:14.317: INFO/DEBUG(27):  ip ad083e5c  sp 44cc8c48  lr ad047361  pc ad03fc86  cpsr 00000030
07-05 10:45:14.487: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #00  pc 0003fc86  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-05 10:45:14.498: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #01  pc 0002f480  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-05 10:45:14.498: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #02  pc 001f3c52  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-05 10:45:14.498: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #03  pc 00260b62  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-05 10:45:14.498: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #04  pc 000dac80  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-05 10:45:14.498: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #05  pc 000ecc6c  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-05 10:45:14.507: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #06  pc 000df90c  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-05 10:45:14.507: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #07  pc 00188640  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-05 10:45:14.507: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #08  pc 001887bc  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-05 10:45:14.507: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #09  pc 001887e8  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-05 10:45:14.507: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #10  pc 00258ab6  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-05 10:45:14.507: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #11  pc 0000e434  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-05 10:45:14.517: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #12  pc 00040b0e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-05 10:45:14.517: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #13  pc 00013198  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-05 10:45:14.517: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #14  pc 00017be4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-05 10:45:14.517: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #15  pc 0001762c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-05 10:45:14.517: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #16  pc 0005282c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-05 10:45:14.517: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #17  pc 0005284a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-05 10:45:14.517: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #18  pc 00047800  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-05 10:45:14.527: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #19  pc 0000f940  /system/lib/libc.so
07-05 10:45:14.527: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #20  pc 0000f4b4  /system/lib/libc.so
07-05 10:45:14.527: INFO/DEBUG(27): stack:
07-05 10:45:14.527: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c08  44cc8c40  
07-05 10:45:14.527: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c0c  00280df0  [heap]
07-05 10:45:14.527: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c10  4182712a  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex
07-05 10:45:14.527: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c14  4182712b  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex
07-05 10:45:14.527: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c18  00280df0  [heap]
07-05 10:45:14.527: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c1c  00000001  
07-05 10:45:14.527: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c20  00000007  
07-05 10:45:14.527: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c24  4106ffe0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
07-05 10:45:14.537: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c28  00280df0  [heap]
07-05 10:45:14.537: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c2c  00000001  
07-05 10:45:14.537: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c30  00000007  
07-05 10:45:14.537: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c34  ad047361  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-05 10:45:14.537: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c38  411b9a50  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
07-05 10:45:14.537: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c3c  00280df0  [heap]
07-05 10:45:14.537: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c40  df002777  
07-05 10:45:14.537: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c44  e3a070ad  
07-05 10:45:14.537: INFO/DEBUG(27): #00 44cc8c48  002cf510  [heap]
07-05 10:45:14.537: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c4c  ad06c894  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-05 10:45:14.537: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c50  ad03ff19  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-05 10:45:14.537: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c54  ad06c608  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-05 10:45:14.537: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c58  439ab0d8  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
07-05 10:45:14.537: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c5c  ad06c608  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-05 10:45:14.547: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c60  ad03fc71  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-05 10:45:14.547: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c64  00297fb8  [heap]
07-05 10:45:14.547: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c68  00000000  
07-05 10:45:14.547: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c6c  ad02f483  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-05 10:45:14.547: INFO/DEBUG(27): #01 44cc8c70  ad06c608  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-05 10:45:14.547: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c74  ad02ff11  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-05 10:45:14.547: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c78  44cc8cac  
07-05 10:45:14.547: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c7c  411b9a50  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
07-05 10:45:14.547: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c80  aa3dc5d0  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-05 10:45:14.547: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c84  ad02f409  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-05 10:45:14.547: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c88  aa1f3c3d  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-05 10:45:14.547: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c8c  00297fb8  [heap]
07-05 10:45:14.547: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c90  00000000  
07-05 10:45:14.547: INFO/DEBUG(27):     44cc8c94  aa1f3c55  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
07-05 10:45:15.077: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Starting activity: Intent { dat=content://com.simpleclock.widget/appwidgets/1 cmp=hobodroid.clock.widget/.Settings (has extras) }
07-05 10:45:15.077: WARN/ActivityManager(70): startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { dat=content://com.simpleclock.widget/appwidgets/1 cmp=hobodroid.clock.widget/.Settings (has extras) }
07-05 10:45:15.577: INFO/Ads(3527): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
07-05 10:45:15.637: INFO/Ads(3527): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://www.gstatic.com/afma/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"msid":"hobodroid.clock.widget","simulator":1,"hl":"en","preqs":2,"u_so":"p","slotname":"a14e0eda6eb26ea","js":"afma-sdk-a-v4.1.0","app_name":"8.android.hobodroid.clock.widget","isu":"B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB","u_audio":4,"u_w":320,"cap":"m,a","format":"320x50_mb","u_sd":1.5,"net":"ed","u_h":533});</script></head><body></body></html>
07-05 10:45:15.877: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Displayed activity hobodroid.clock.widget/.Settings: 796 ms (total 796 ms)
07-05 10:45:16.887: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Process hobodroid.clock.widget (pid 3527) has died.
07-05 10:45:16.887: WARN/ActivityManager(70): Scheduling restart of crashed service hobodroid.clock.widget/.ClockService in 5000ms
07-05 10:45:16.897: INFO/WindowManager(70): WIN DEATH: Window{43856840 hobodroid.clock.widget/hobodroid.clock.widget.Settings paused=false}
07-05 10:45:16.937: WARN/UsageStats(70): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in hobodroid.clock.widget
07-05 10:45:16.987: ERROR/ActivityThread(70): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
07-05 10:45:16.987: WARN/Checkin(70): Can't log event SYSTEM_SERVICE_LOOPING: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://android.server.checkin/events
07-05 10:45:16.997: WARN/InputManagerService(70): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 3527 uid 10024
```

Comment: I see similar issues.  1.6 version of emulator.  Usually happens after an orientation change for me.  Just annoying, and making debugging difficult.  Test mode doesn't help.  To use test mode, just add the line: adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR); before loadAd

Answer (score 0):

This issue is discussed here https://groups.google.com/group/google-admob-ads-sdk/browse_thread/thread/f72ed8694a28cc7d/ced66f77ddb1e3ad and here http://groups.google.com/group/google-admob-ads-sdk/browse_thread/thread/eeb307a33a69765d. The suggested workaround is to call adView.destroy() in Activity.onDestroy(). Seems to help.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    //workaround for AdMob crash on 1.6
    AdView adView=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    if(adView!=null)
        adView.destroy();
}
```