# AdMob seems to work only on some devices. doesn't work on galaxy s, s2

Tags: android, admob

I've made an app and embedded AdMob in it as it shows on the tutorial.

It seems to work ok on my Samsung S3 and also show on emulator.

When trying it on Samsung S and S2 the ads simply doesn't show..

any idea why?

Here's my code:

```
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calc);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        match = intent.getStringExtra(StartActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a150b2362fba949");
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.calcL);
        layout.addView(adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest()); }




    and XML:



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/calcL"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
     >
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="8" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="30sp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/calc" />

     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout 


        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="2" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Are you certain that your phone is connected to the internet? Also if you have an adblocker on your phone make sure that is disabled

Comment: I think the versions of those phones are 2.3.5 and 2.3.6. , mabye my code works only for android 4???

Comment: both phones are connected to the internet and both doesn't have any adblocker on them

Comment: Why not try inserting the using XML to see if it is your code - https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals

Comment: tried with XML, Still Same results

Comment: Have you looked here ? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049737/making-admob-work-on-android-2-3-device

Comment: logcat says 11-26 00:32:18.025: E/ActivityThread(599): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
when i'm running it on the device

Comment: @jcw i just did, still no luck :|

Comment: What about here, its not quite the same, but the answers might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580201/admob-crashes-emulator-when-launching-app-repeatedly